# Ada: Array of tasks

Tags: arrays, concurrency, task, ada

What is a good way to link an indexed task to a corresponding indexed protected type in SPARK?

For specifics, consider this setup:

```
subtype Thread_Range is Natural range 1..n;
protected type P is ... end P;
p: array(Thread_Range) of P;
```

For each `p(i)` I would like a task `t(i)` that monitors `p(i)` and, when it's ready, processes it. I can make this work pretty easily in Ada, but SPARK w/Ravenscar is more demanding. I've tried two approaches that appear to work fine when I run them:

1. Give `T` an `Integer` discriminant, then instantiate a `T(i);` for each `i`, but this grows burdensome with not-very-large `i`.

```
task type T(which: Integer);
t1: T(1);
t2: T(2);
...
```

2. Add an `is_not_monitored` function and a `set_monitor` procedure to `P`. Create an array of tasks *without* discriminant. When `t(i)` begins, it assigns itself to monitor the first `p(j)` it finds that hasn't already been assigned a monitor.

```
task type T;
task body T is
  which: Integer;
  available: Boolean;
begin
  for i in Thread_Range loop
    available := p(i).is_not_monitored;
    if available then
      p(i).set_monitor;
      which := i;
    end if;
  end loop;
  -- what the task does with p(i) follows
end T;
t: array(Thread_Range) of T;
```

I like the second one better, but not by much. In any case, SPARK "Prove" grumbles about potential data races, and I can see why (though I'm not sure it's actually due to this).

Hence the question.

Comment: Could you add another protected object with a single procedure  `Get_Next_Available_Index(Next : out Thread_Range)`?

Comment: That makes sense, and I like it better than the other options. I'll try it & let you know.

Comment: Strange. The program works fine, but "Examine" and "Prove" give me `GNAT BUG DETECTED`. I guess that's one way of getting SPARK to stop grumbling...

Comment: (to be specific, the error is `Constraint_Error erroneous memory access`)

Comment: @egilhh Thinking about your answer (& having implemented it in a different program, since SPARK has decided to crash on my original): Is it in not equivalent to the second approach above? Seems to me that it just moves `is_not_monitored` and (possibly) the monitor flags to the other protected object. FWIW, SPARK seems happy with the second approach when I place it in a new project.

Comment: Aside: I figured out why SPARK wasn't checking things. Not so much why it was crashing, but it's working well with both now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This doesn’t cause gnatprove to choke.

And I think the main difference from your option 2 is that `Claim` checks whether the claim is possible and, if so, performs the claim in one protected call.

But I don’t quite see how to prove that the loop `Claim` in `T` exits with `Ps (J)` being claimed. I tried putting an assertion after the loop, but couldn’t get it to prove.

```
protected type P is
   procedure Claim (Succeeded : out Boolean);
private
   Claimed : Boolean := False;
end P;

subtype Thread_Range is Integer range 1 .. 2;

Ps : array (Thread_Range) of P;

Ts : array (Thread_Range) of T;

task body T is
   Which : Integer;
begin
Claim:
   for J in Thread_Range loop
      declare
         Claimed : Boolean;
      begin
         Ps (J).Claim (Succeeded => Claimed);
         if Claimed then
            Which := J;
            exit Claim;
         end if;
      end;
   end loop Claim;

   loop  -- having a loop keeps gnatprove quiet
      delay until Ada.Real_Time.Time_Last;
   end loop;
end T;

protected body P is
   procedure Claim (Succeeded : out Boolean) is
   begin
      if not Claimed then
         Claimed := True;
         Succeeded := True;
      else
         Succeeded := False;
      end if;
   end Claim;
end P;
```

---

After out-of-band discussions with John, we’ve found that this postcondition can be proved:

```
  procedure Claim (Succeeded : out Boolean)
  with
    Post =>
      (Is_Claimed'Old or (Succeeded and Is_Claimed))
      or
      (not Succeeded and Is_Claimed);
```

Note that it’s not `P’Old.Is_Claimed`, mainly because `’Old` requires a copy, and `P` is limited (because it’s a protected type).

We also found several alternative formulations that prove in GPL 2017 but not in CE 2018: for example,

```
      (Is_Claimed
       and
       (Is_Claimed'Old xor Succeeded)
```

Comment: How does one set a postcondition on a loop? I have something similar, and I set a postcondition on `P.Claim` and that passes through SPARK. But I have the feeling that that's not what you mean.

Comment: I’d have liked to set a postcondition on `P.Claim` to say that if `P’Old` was claimed, `Succeeded` would be `False` etc, but `P’Old` isn’t possible for a limited type, and anyway you’d need a function to determine whether `P` was claimed or not, and it’d be volatile, and that’s illegal in this context. I did manage an assertion after the loop (but couldn’t prove it, see lack of skills above)

Comment: This is the solution I was looking for, and more importantly what I'm seeing is that technique #2, which I liked, was actually on the right track. The Gnatprove errors I was getting were in fact related to something else. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I'm not an expert in this, but it seems that you cannot show SPARK that there's a one-to-one relation between a task instance and a protected object instance unless you reference that protected object instance explicitly from a task instance. This is in particular to make SPARK prove that only one task will queue on the entry of a protected object; the `Wait` entry in the code below). Therefore (and while this might not be exactly what you're looking for), I could only solve the problem of connecting tasks and protected objects, and at the same time having a monitor functionality, by using a generic package that can be instantiated multiple times. This proves in GNAT CE 2018:

```
generic
package Generic_Worker with SPARK_Mode is   

   task T;

   protected P is
      entry Wait;
      procedure Trigger;
   private
      Triggered : Boolean := False;
   end P;

end Generic_Worker;
```

with body:

```
package body Generic_Worker with SPARK_Mode is

   task body T is      
   begin
      loop   --  Ravenscar: Tasks must not terminate.         
         P.Wait;
      end loop;
   end T;

   protected body P is

      entry Wait when Triggered is
      begin
         Triggered := False; 
         --  Do some work.
      end Wait;

      procedure Trigger is
      begin
         Triggered := True;
      end Trigger;

   end P;

end Generic_Worker;
```

and instantiations:

```
with Generic_Worker;

pragma Elaborate_All (Generic_Worker);

package Workers with SPARK_Mode is

   package Worker_0 is new Generic_Worker;
   package Worker_1 is new Generic_Worker;
   package Worker_2 is new Generic_Worker;
   package Worker_3 is new Generic_Worker;
   package Worker_4 is new Generic_Worker;

end Workers;
```

Comment: Thank you for taking a look at it! I think you may have misunderstood the question, though; I didn't necessarily want to prove that a particular task was linked to a particular protected object; I just wanted an array of protected objects, each of which corresponds to one task of an equal number of tasks, and I wanted to do it without creating specific objects. As I'm learning SPARK, figuring out a good technique has been tough. Your solution looks like an improvement of technique #1 above, and while I like the improvement, I actually don't like that technique (e.g., if `n` is variable).